# Woocommerce redirects to wrong product link in mobile view

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hyperlink, product

I use Woocommerce for the webshop. In the desktop-version all of the links work when I click on a product. However, in the mobile (and split screen) view of the website, when I click on a product, it keeps redirecting it to the latest product that I added. And that happens no matter on which product I click.

Link to the webshop: https://ecsense.com/ec-sense-products/

I hope someone could help me figure out what is going wrong here. Thank You!

Greetings.

Comment: You are opening different products but shows content of one product. So the problem is in your single product page. If you open inspector you will see that product id is correct but information is from different product.

Comment: From further inspection i see that the content of the missing product is loaded just with display none css rule. So check your templates. Its Divi theme so contact theyr support for best solution